# execute as sudo in fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I have a command `service app start-demo` requires me to type `sudo service app start-demo` in the command line.

I used `sudo(service app start-demo)` and `sudo(sudo service app start-demo)` but I still get

Warning: sudo() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'sudo service app start-demo'

I have no problem executing that as a command line in a terminal.

I am not sure if `SADeprecationWarning:` counts as a failure to fabric?

Thanks.

---

```
user@box:/var/lib/app$ fab kickstart
You are installing prereqs..........
### Install Prereqs for Populate ###
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection: localhost
[localhost] Login password: 

### I am starting demo ###
[localhost] sudo: sudo service app start-demo
[localhost] out: Starting demo

Fatal error: sudo() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'sudo service app start-demo'

Aborting.
Disconnecting from localhost... done.
```

the code

```
def pserve():
    print '### I am starting demo ###'
    #with settings(warn_only=True):
    sudo('sudo service app start-demo')
    #sudo('service app start-demo')
```

either `sudo` command will fail.

---

`/etc/sudoers`

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults    env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command after they have
# provided their password
# (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
# it further down)
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: Does your `sudo` configuration require you to type a password at the terminal?

Comment: Did you put the command in quotes?  It should be `sudo("service app start-demo")`.

Comment: @sarnold It doesn't. When I do `sudo` on terminal, it won't ask. I ran as fab it didn't ask either.

Comment: @mayhewr Oh yes. MY bad. I do. Otherwise, it would complain as syntactic error. :))

Comment: SADeprecationWarning should not be the problem.  Even if it were, the service would still start (since it certainly knows it's just a warning), but fabric could report it as a failure.  If the service doesn't start, the problem must be somewhere else.  If you're still having the problem, post a more complete traceback/output.

Comment: @mayhewr Thanks. I've updated with a complete log. Is that what you need? If not, please let me know.

Comment: @user423455: so you have configured whatever you want to run in `/etc/sudoers` as `NOPASSWD`? Because the cached password you gave in your own shell for a test run of the command with `sudo` *may* not actually be useful to the command you're trying to run here.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Hi there. Thanks. Shouldn't `fab` uses the current user as the sudo account, and asks for access? Or is that not so? I believe I did. I am posting the file in just a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is prolly related to this mention in the [faq](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work), but also if the command doesn't return 0 (unix standard for all good) it'll fail-fast unless you tell it to warn only.

Comment: Thansk! That's a very good finding :) Now.. one more thing... fab doesn't return. It just waits there. Why is that?

Comment: Most likely due to some nohup or backgrounding stuff, also [mentioned in the FAQ](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang)